# Generate PDF under Symfony6

Tags: pdf, symfony6, knp-snappy

I host my Symfony6 project a mutualized which is a handicap for the use of KnpSnappyBundle, I want to use another bundle that supports my boosterap styles. A bit like KnpSnappyBundle does. Because with Dompdf, I’m not doing very well.

I tried Dompdf and Qipsiustcpdfbundle
But I expect what would help me generate PDF directly from my TWIG pages